# Boost Converter/ Inverting Converter Noise Measurement

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I built a boost/inverting converter using TPS65130. The output voltage is +15V and - 15V. Below is a picture of the schematics:
[image]

I know the schematics shows a zener diode symbol, but that's just a mistake. I'm using a schottky diode. Also, the base of U37 is not connected because I have a zero ohm resistor across R50. U41 is an LT3094 and U42 is an LT3045, they are both linear regulators used to filter noise.
What I'm trying to do is to measure the noise of the power supply. Here is the procedure that I followed to measure the noise of this power supply:

1. used a 1:1 probe that has a max bandwidth of 35Mhz.
2. used a bandwidth limit of 20Mhz on the oscilloscope.
3. used a ground spring instead of the long ground lead. I also made sure there is nothing else connected to the oscilloscope picking up common mode noise.
4. I measured directly at the output capacitor C152 for the boost and c179 for the inverting converter.
5. the load current is 80mA.
6. AC coupling.

The problem is I noticed some weird overshoot and undershoot. The first picture shows what I see when I measure directly across C152 which is the positive supply:
[image]

The next picture is what I see when I measure across C150 which is after the linear regulator:
[image]
The Next picture is what I see when I measure across C179 which is the negative supply:
[image]

The final one is if I measure across C1 Which is after the linear regulator:
[image]

I have checked everything including the inductor and output capacitors. Checked things like saturation current, rating current, etc. These waveforms repeat and when I measure the frequency between two repeating waveforms, I get 6Hz. This is the same for both the positive and negative supplies.
Any Idea on what this could be?

Edit: I noticed that the problem disappear if I lower the input voltage to 4V. Not sure why does it work with 4v better than 5V.
Edit2: zoomed picture of the ripple on the positive power supply.
[image]

Comment: Is this a problem? It looks to be only a few millivolts, which shouldn't be a problem for most things. What's your load?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how much of a problem it is. I'm using it to power an op-amp circuit. I just think usually with sensitive analog circuits, you want the lowest amount of noise possible. Also, I just honestly found it to be weird.

Comment: What is the output voltage from the boost converter? Maybe I'm misreading the values in the diagram, but I get 1.213*(1+976k/110k) = 12v, which can't be right if you're generating 15v.  Also, 121k (I think, hard to read) on the LT3045 is also 12v, so I think you aren't regulating?

Comment: Instead of powering an op amp circuit, try connecting a resistive load instead and make the noise measurements. Maybe your op amp circuit is drawing bursts of current at 6kHz. Also, check if your DC-DC converter and linear regulator have been compensated properly and have an adequate amount of output capacitance.

Comment: As far as the output voltage, you are absolutely right. The output voltage is 12V not 15V. That was a mistake in the schematics. That shouldn't cause any problem for my circuit though.

Comment: I will try to use a different load. I did notice that when I lower the load current or lower the voltage, the problem disappear. I looked at the waveform on the inductor for the negative supply, and I noticed that when I lower the load current, I see ringing on the square wave indicating that the negative power supply is now in DCM mode. When I lower the voltage, the ringing disappear. This indicates that the negative supply is CCM mode. At 5V exactly, the negative supply is in CCM mode, but I notice some very quick glitch in the inductor waveform.

Comment: I think at 5V the inverting converter is somehow in between CCM and DCM, which could be the cause of my problem, but I'm not sure though.

Comment: I also posted a picture of the ripple of the supply. It doesn't look like a sawtooth wave. Is this normal?

Comment: The linear regulators are also set to 12V though, so that won't work. You need to output a higher voltage due to the nonzero drop out voltage on the linear regulators.

Comment: You are right about that. I'm measuring about 12V on the output though. In the end, I'm not too concerned about it being 12V exactly as long as it's being regulated. I did notice that at 5V, the negative supply was switching really fast between what it seemed like CCM and DCM. It was hard to catch, but I'm managed to see that and I used zone triggering which showed me that it was operating at DCM at that particular moment in time. It's just a theory, but maybe this fast switching between CCM and DCM is causing the chip to be unstable at 5V and this much load, but that's just a theory.

Comment: I mean the linear regulators are not working because (if what you said is accurate) you haven't powered them past dropout.  Presumably you want them to reduce that noise from your switching power supply?  Try setting the output voltage on the switching converter to 13 or 14 V and it should go away.

Comment: Well, I think what's happening is that the switching supply is giving an output of something close to 12V but not 12V exactly. When the 12V enters the linear regulator which has a wide input range from 1.8V to 20V. The voltage regulator should take a dropout of 235 mV according to the datasheet, so the output won't be effected as much. The linear regulator is on and is reducing some of the noise at the output. It's not a 12V linear regulator, it excepts a wide input voltage range and outputs anywhere between 0V and 15V. I see your point, you thought that the regulator is a 12V regulator.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what a linear regulator does.  The drop out is not how much it decreases voltage, it is how much extra voltage you need to turn on the regulator.  In the circuit you have drawn, and under the conditions you described, 12v is not a valid voltage to power a LT3045 regulator, so it is not on.  The absolute minimum would be 12.26V, and if you want the full noise reduction, you need ~12.5V.  So either you are wrong about the regulator being on or you are mistaken about your voltage.  Figure out which is wrong and you'll probably have your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your positive rail and reading off the resistor values, I get that your output voltage is 1.213*(1+976k/110k) = 12v (rather than 15v).

Proceeding onto the linear regulator, you put the set pin to 121 kohm, which is 12v output.  Hence, you are feeding an LDO 12v and telling it to generate 12v.  That isn't possible, so the LDO is in dropout and so you see lots of noise on the output.  You need to fix that.

Before you do, take a look at the PSRR as a function of voltage for your linear regulator:

[image: PSRR vs voltage]

The regulator turns on at about 300 mV and starts regulating, but its performance is extremely degraded.  Increasing that to 1V (so 13v in) gives you 20-30dB better PSRR.  Increasing it to 2V (so 14V) gets you another 10dB rejection at your boost converter frequency.  If you're buying an expensive high PSRR regulator, you almost certainly want that extra 30-40dB!  Set the output voltage to +/-15v like you said originally and (assuming good layout) you'll reduce that noise voltage by a factor of 10,000, which will put your noise into the low microvolt amplitude.

Comment: I finally understand what you were saying. I even forgot that I put a 121k ohm on the set pin, that's why I was confused. I was fixated on knowing the reason behind the odd waveforms on the boost converter that I didn't notice the mistake. Hopefully, this will help filter all that noise. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Analog No problem, it actually jumped out at me since I was laying out something similar with the TPS65130 recently (but using cheaper regulators).